# Port forwarding raspberry pi not working

Tags: port-forwarding

I've recently needed to forward a port to run an FTP server on my raspberry pi, but after I failed, I went to test running it on my pc, but the port forward didn't work there either. 
I have forwarded my ports in my router, disabled firewall, checked connection, IPs, everything, but the port won't open no matter what. Strange thing is that there are some ports mapped by UPnP and all of those work and are open. But if I try to create a mapping manually it doesn't work no matter what I try. I checked the settings a dozen of times, they are exactly identical to the UPnP mappings (except the port of course). There are no firewalls in my PC nor my router, and there are no other routers that would block the ports.

I'm really desperate for a solution, have been trying to figure it out all day.

Comment: You haven't really provided much information for us to go on. Can you post the output of `netstat -lptn` and give us some information regarding how you have configured port forwarding on your router.

Comment: Is that port open for FTP specifically? Or are you talking also about other applications which do not work? Which router manufacturer/model do you own?

Comment: Ok so it appears that for some reason I can't forward port 21. I put the server on a different port (221) and now it seems to be open (the port) but the server still doesn't work:
Server sent passive reply with unroutable address 192.168.1.13, using host address instead.
Transfer channel can't be opened. Reason: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a different program (vsftpd) for the FTP server and it seems to be running fine.